# Nginx is not giving client ip

Tags: nginx

I have two environment of my nodejs backend - dev and production. The dev one is hoisted on iis and the other one is on nginx. Now I want the real ip of my client in backend in order to maintain a record that which user has logged into his account using which ip. So for that i have configured my nodejs backend and both webservers i.e., iis and nginx and i am able to get the client ip on my dev environment (hoisted on iis) but when i try the same on my production environment (hoisted on nginx) i am getting the ip address of my router instead of client ip in xff (x-forwarded-for) header. How to resolve it?

## nginx conf

```
server{
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name creativeease.app www.creativeease.app;

        ssl_certificate /home/creativeeaseweb/creative-ease-web-backend/ssl/bundled.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/creativeeaseweb/creative-ease-web-backend/ssl/priv.key;

        root /var/www/html/creative-ease-web-frontend/dist;
        index index.html;

        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;

}
```

## creativebackend.conf

```
location /cew-backend {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/api;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

## my nodejs conf

```
function loadConfiguration() {
  try {
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.json({ limit: process.env.SERVER_JSON_LIMIT }));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: process.env.SERVER_JSON_LIMIT }));
    app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
    app.use(cors({ origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL, credentials: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use('/api', routes);

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing')
      return https.createServer(ssl(process.env.SSL_CERT_KEY_PATH, process.env.SSL_CERT_PATH), app);

    app.set('trust proxy', true);

    return app;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occured during configuring the server.', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

## Note

The dev environment is only accessible on private n/w not on public n/w i.e., through mobile sim internet.

i have configured the nginx to pass the xff header to my backend and it is passing also but i am not getting the client ip as its value instead i am getting my router's ip.